# Как сделать код более компактным

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, как можно более компактно записать такой код:

```
public void UpdateSelectedInfo()
{
    string text1 = "...";
    string text2 = "...";    
    //..    
    string text8 = "...";

    if      (mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 0 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 15 ||
            mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 16 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 31)
        mainWindow.textBox2.Text = text1;
    else if (mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 1 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 14 ||
            mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 17 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 30)
        mainWindow.textBox2.Text = text2;
    else if (mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 2 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 13 ||
            mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 18 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 29)
        mainWindow.textBox2.Text = text3;
    else if (mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 3 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 12 ||
            mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 19 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 28)
        mainWindow.textBox2.Text = text4;
    else if (mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 4 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 11 ||
            mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 20 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 27)
        mainWindow.textBox2.Text = text5;
    else if (mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 5 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 10 ||
            mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 21 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 26)
        mainWindow.textBox2.Text = text6;
    else if (mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 6 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 9  ||
            mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 22 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 25)
        mainWindow.textBox2.Text = text7;
    else if (mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 7 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 8  ||
            mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 23 || mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo == 24)
        mainWindow.textBox2.Text = text8;
}
```

Цифры 0..31 - это индексы зубов. Если нажать на определенный зуб, то отображается его текстовое описание. То есть для четырех одинаковых зубов будет одно описание, для четырех других - другое и т.д.

Comment: Вы, видимо, хотели использовать [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/06tc147t.aspx)

Comment: Вам вовсе не должно такого хотеться. У вас вместо индекса должна быть структура данных, описывающая зуб, в которой есть его положение (сверху/снизу, справа/слева), позиция от центра, название и всё, что нужно. Если индекс получается из списка, используйте не цикл по индексам, а foreach, и не SelectedIndex, а SelectedItem. Индексы — зло и каменный век.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```
string[] texts = new string[] {"...", "...", /* ... */ "..."};
int[] indexMap = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
mainWindow.textBox2.Text = texts[indexMap[mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo]];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public static int SelectionIndexToTeethIndex(int selectionIndex)
{
    if (selectionIndex / 8 % 2 == 1)
    {
        selectionIndex = 31 - selectionIndex;
    }
    return selectionIndex % 8;
}

var texts = new string[] { "Text1", "Text2", ... };
mainWindow.textBox2.Text = texts[SelectionIndexToTeethIndex(mainWindow.IndexForSelectedInfo)];
```